# Override Material UI component with SASS classes

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, material-ui

I am utilizing Material UI components but want to move all my styles into a `.scss` file. Currently, I have a large styles object in the same javascript file where I use the Material UI components. This styles object is being passed to the Material UI components via the `style` prop. This as I see it is more or less just inline styling and my goal is to eliminate this pattern. I have other nested components (Material UI ones as well as custom React ones) within these Material UI components. Here is an example I am working with:

```
 const styles= {//all my css styles in here}

<TableRowColumn key={index} style={styles.column}>
     <span className="checkbox-thing">
       <input
         ....
       />
     </span>
</TableRowColumn>
```

I have referenced the override documentation: https://material-ui-next.com/customization/overrides/

As well as this Stack Overflow question: [How to style material ui next components with styled components and SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46930275/how-to-style-material-ui-next-components-with-styled-components-and-sass)

Both of these in my opinion do not make it clear how to go about using an external `.scss` (where the styles would live) and referencing the class names in that file into the Material UI component. I simply was to be able to do something like this, which is currently easy to accomplish with normal HTML elements:

```
<input   
    type="checkbox"
    checked={
      this.props.isChecked
    }
    className="someClassInTheSCSSFile"
/>
```

In summary I want to:

- Remove my large styles object into separate classes into a `.scss` file
- Reference a class in the  `.scss` file and pop it into a Material UI component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no rhyme or reason as to why this started working now as opposed to when I had tried before, but using `className="someClassInTheSCSSFile"` ended up working provided my `.scss` file contained something similar to:

```
//.scss file

.someClassInTheSCSSFile {
   color: blue;
   //rest of the styles go here
}
```

In summary, using the `className` prop directly inside MATERIAL UI components works. So using the example code from my question the following works:

```
//Javascript file

<TableRowColumn key={index} className="someClassInTheSCSSFile">
 <span className="checkbox-thing">
   <input
     ....
   />
 </span>
</TableRowColumn>
```

Now, what is actually really interesting (and disappointing) is when you want to pass a value to the CSS. For example, say this `TableRowColumn` component has a `width` attribute but I do not want to hard code it into my `.scss` file. Sticking with my pattern of not using any inline styling, this presents a challenge. Lets says this `TableRowColumn` component is inside a function that takes a parameter called `colWidth`. When the function is called, I want to then dynamically pass this `colWidth` value into my css `width` attribute of this `TableRowColumn` component. However, this ends up, as far as I can tell, being an impossible task at the moment. What can be done is:

```
//Javascript File

<TableRowColumn key={index} style={{width:`${coldWidth}`}} className="someClassInTheSCSSFile">
 <span className="checkbox-thing">
   <input
     ....
   />
 </span>
</TableRowColumn>
```

But this is inline styling. Exactly what I was trying to avoid. So now, I end up having both inline styling AND a `className` that references my `.scss` file. Arguably more clunky and burdensome. How about if I use the `attr()` function inside my `.scss`? Well, according to MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) this will only support Strings being passed and all other types are not supported in mainstream browsers. Ouch. Refer to this codepen (https://jsfiddle.net/hmr0hckf/131/) for an example of this in action. Moral of the story, I'm stuck with inline styling for any css attribute where I want to dynamically alter the value.

Answer (score 0):

#### Webpack with node-sass and sass-loader

You're pretty close. Put all of your styles into one or many .scss files, like you normally would. For example, a class named "nodeContent."

```
.nodeContent {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

All you need to do is import your styles and access the class names as property of your styles object. See below in this example I have a Sass file named `styles.scss` in the same directory as my component. In my component I can import them like this:

```
import * as styles from './styles.scss'
```

The styles is an object and I can reference my classes like I would any other property of an object. So if I want to use the nodeContent class on a material component, I can do this:

```
<Card className={styles.nodeContent} />
```

#### Without using webpack (not 100% sure on this)

I think you can compile your .scss files to .css and reference them as a  in your index.html file. After that, I think you should be able to reference the classNames as a string like you showed above. 
Here's the article I just read that is similar, except they import the css file in their component: https://hackernoon.com/using-sass-with-create-react-app-without-ejecting-b5f4f827ed9e

Comment: Directly importing my `.scss` in this way is giving me a 404

Comment: Hmm... interesting. Are you using webpack?

Comment: I am not using webpack

Comment: I see. I was assuming you were using webpack with node-sass and sass-loader, my bad. In your case, I think you can compile your .scss files to .css and reference them as a <link> in your index.html file. After that, I think you should be able to reference the classNames as a string like you showed above. Here's the article I just read that is similar, except they import the css file in their component. https://hackernoon.com/using-sass-with-create-react-app-without-ejecting-b5f4f827ed9e

Comment: Refer to my updated answer. This ended up being disappointing, thank you anyway.